# Mysql statement to insert rows at bottom of table instead of position where last row was deleted?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just deleted a row from my mysql table.

Now whenever I write the statement "INSERT INTO myTable" a new row is added at the position in the table where the last row was deleted.

How do I modify the "INSERT INTO myTable" statement so that rows are added to the bottom of the table?

EDIT:

For clarification this is the php code I use to print the stuff in the database

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM People") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>FirstName</th> <th>LastName</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['FirstName'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['LastName'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";
```

And it's printing the last row I added in the middle of the table in the same position of the last row that I deleted.

Comment: i don't get the question. sql naturally does not know any ordering, so there is no top or bottom rows

Comment: @knittl is right. @LedZeppelin: Why do you think that rows are added at the position in the table where the last row was deleted? Have you been reading the disks with an external tool to find the actual place in the disk/file that the row has been saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually depends on storage engine and primary key. But better do not rely on the phisical order of the data, but specify `ORDER BY` in your queries.

Answer (score 4):

I can only assume you are referring to to the ordering of records as returned in a SELECT without ORDER BY. You should not rely on this order at all. A different RDBMS, or even a different version or configuration of MySQL may behave differently.

Add an ID from a sequence and select the records ordered by that field, if you don't already have something monotonic.